# How to only count one vote per a proposal by each unique ID on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

We are setting up a form that is used for a student conference to score different proposals. Students fill out the form with their last name, their voter ID, their committee, the proposal number, and then grade the proposal on five different topics. The responses are sent to a google sheet. We use a separate sheet to query the responses so we can use formulas to calculate the scores. Here are the columns and what each does.

Timestamp- Time of vote

Last Name-Last name entered on form

Student ID-Student ID entered on form

Proposal Number- Proposal Number

National Relevance; Feasibility; Debatability; Evidence of research; Creativity - Scoring categories

StudentID Last name - looks up the last name associated with the StudentID entered from StudentData sheet

StudentID Committee - looks up the student's committee from the StudentData sheet based on StudentID

CommitteeName (there are several) - `=iferror(IF(AND(TRIM(StudendID Last Name)=TRIM(Last Name),TRIM(StudentID Committee)=(CommitteeName)),SUM(Scoring Categories),""),"")`

So we have figured out how to validate that the student entered the correct last name based on the id they input in order for their vote to count. The only issue is this will still count if a student has voted twice for the same proposal.

In another sheet, we us an AVERAGEIFS function to average the scores for each proposal number and committee that was input between two times (start and stop of voting).

We would like a way to add to the formula in the CommitteeName columns to only count one vote for each proposal number by a unique studentID so students can't vote twice. Is there a formula we can use here or would it be best to add this criteria to the AVERAGEIFS function where we average the scores? We're not sure what formula we would use in the AVERAGEIFS function. We thought of using UNIQUE but weren't sure if that would discard the student's votes on other proposals since each proposal is voted on using the same form.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Remember that we can't see what you can see. As such, post explanations without clear and complete windows to the data and layout are like calling a mechanic who's never seen your car, saying, "My car's acting weird and making a sound like crch-rch-rch. What's wrong with it? Can you tell me how to fix it? I won't be able to bring it in, though." (Really, that's a pretty close analogy.) The most efficient and effective way to get help is to share a link to your spreadsheet (or a copy of it, or a solid sample from it), with the Share permission set to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor."